# How to pause/resume downloads in iPhone (iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, download

I have to download large amount of data (anywhere between **300MB - 1GB**).

I am currently using `**NSURLConnection**`to download the data. But, now i am looking at a scenario where the user might loose the internet connection during the download process. Currently i am restarting the entire download process in this scenario, which i think is a very bad way of downloading and a waste of user bandwidth.

**Is there a process in which i can manage the downloads with Pause/Resume functionality while downloading**.

Answer (score 1):

this needs synchronization both at server as well as client side. and i allready told u to use chunks. definetely chunks is the only solution if you want to pause. you will send the server with a chunk id to stop till this i'll get remaing next and next time you will ask from that id.

Comment: thanks for the response saad... Can you please be more specific technically. I mean, can you explain a bit more on how to do it... Any links would also be helpful

Comment: sorry no idea about link. you may google it. infact i implemented some thing similar to this in my app. the thing is server sends a message having information about the number of packets to be receive. the client sends ok and communication starts, whenever the client needs to  pause. it will send a message through webservice that stop till now, that i have received these packets. next time when client will request the resume process, it server had the information of last sent packets, so it will start sending remaining packets, the basic thing is to shift most your working on server side.

Comment: Are u talking something similar to RANGE HEADERS on the server side?

Answer (score -1):

You can use "NSURLSession to pause and resume