# Alamofire Pause Request not contine other Requests wating in Queue

Tags: ios, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire library to make a download manager.

- I'm configuring the Alamofire Manager with
  `HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 4`.
- And I'm start Downloading 5 items, then 4 items start downloading and
  the the 5th item is waiting in queue.
- When I Pause one of the first 4th item, I'm expecting the 5th item to
  start downloading. This is not happening and this is my issue

This is my Code:

```
func startDownload(thisItem url: String, folderName: String) {

let startDownloadRequest = AlamofireManager!.download(.GET, url,
    destination: { temporaryURL, response in
        let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let directoryURL = fileManager.URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)[0]
        self.createFolderWithName(folderName)
        let pathComponent = "\(folderName)/\(response.suggestedFilename!)"            
        return directoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(pathComponent)
})
    .progress { bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())
        {
            let progress = String(Float(totalBytesRead) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToRead))
        }
    }
    .response { _, _, _, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed with error: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Downloaded file successfully")
            }
        }
}
```

And this is the method for Pause Request

```
    func pauseDownload(thisItem item: String) {
    var request : Request
    for req in DownloadCenter.defaultCenter.currentDownloadsList {
        if req.request?.URLString == item {
            request = req
            request.suspend()
            break
        }
    }
}
```

This is my case:
Start Downloading 5 items, 4 are Downloading and the 5th item is waiting..
[image]

After Pausing...
[image]

Comment: Pausing the task doesn't remove it from the queue unlike a completion or a cancelation. There's still 4 active tasks in the queue.

Comment: I knew that, how to cancel the active request but when downloading it again it will resume on the downloaded data not starting from the first ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pause/resume downloads in iPhone (iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414201/how-to-pause-resume-downloads-in-iphone-ios)

Comment: It's not duplicate question, I didn't find a question with my need..

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't had to present this topic as a duplicate, but it should help you with your issue.